# Mock os.remove in Python with unittest.mock

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

How do I mock `os.remove` with `unittest.mock`?

My attempt (using `pytest`)

```
def test_patch_remove():
    with patch("os.remove"):
        remove('foo')
```

gives the error

> ```
>     remove('foo') E           FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'foo'
> ```

indicating that remove has not been mocked.

Comment: Looks like you import `from os import remove`. In this case you have to mock `remove` in the _current module_ (see [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6)). It should work if you `import os` and use `os.remove` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two possibilities: either you mock the module `os` and use `remove` from the module (`test_remove1`), or you do `from os import remove`, and mock the copy in your own module (`test_remove2`):

**test_remove.py**

```
import os
from os import remove
from mock import patch

def test_remove1():
    with patch('os.remove'):
        os.remove('foo')

def test_remove2():
    with patch('test_remove.remove'):
        remove('foo')
```

In a real test the import will happen in another module, so the second case has to be adapted to patch that module.