# mock isdir() instead of os.path.isdir() function in unittests

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

My code use isdir() instead of os.path.isdir(). In my opinion, the first is more readable if occurs multiple times in code.
When is tried to unittest the mocking does not works. The test does not pass and get the Exception.
Can I mock isdir() without change to name in the source code to os.path.isdir()?

Source code

```
from os.path import isdir

def check_path_existence(self, path_to_check):
    if isdir(path_to_check):
        pass
    else:
        raise Exception("Directory does not exists")
```

Test:

```
@patch("os.path.isdir")
def test_check_path_existence(self, mock_isdir):
    mock_isdir.return_value = True

    self.assertIsNone(check_path_existence("invalid_path")
```

Comment: You have to mock the `isdir` instance in the module that uses it instead of `os.path.isdir`, see [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mock os.remove in Python with unittest.mock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61610719/mock-os-remove-in-python-with-unittest-mock). There are many similar questions, I just found this one as I answered it myself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on of MrBean Bremen's comment:

If the module that you're testing has an import path like `mypackage.mymodule`, then you'd want to write your mock like this:

```py
@patch("mypackage.mymodule.isdir")
def test_check_path_existence(self, mock_isdir):
    mock_isdir.return_value = True

    self.assertIsNone(check_path_existence("invalid_path")
```

This way, you're mocking the instance of `isdir` that's in the namespace of your module. Patching the original import path `os.path.isdir` only works if your module uses the `isdir` function by referencing it as an attribute of `os.path`, which you've decided against for stylistic reasons.